# adding online profile pages to moderncv

Tags: macros, moderncv

I have been using [moderncv](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) and I was thinking of adding my *stackoverflow* and *github* profiles to my resume, unfortunately there doesn't seem any macros for that (is there?)

I wasn't using `\homepage{..}` so I added one of the profiles there. If I add another `\homepage{..}`, the first one disappears so I tried adding the other one with `\extrainfo{..}`. It looks ok this way but the problem is first link is clickable while the second one isn't.

So my question is:

- how can I add two `\homepage{..}` 's
- and/or how can I make `\extrainfo{..}` clickable
- and/or how hard it is to maybe create a macro specific to online profiles like `\profilepage{..}` (I don't have any experience with macros).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\extrainfo` is the way to go. To create a link, use `\httplink`, i.e.

```
\extrainfo{%
  \httplink{www.github.com/me}\\%
  \httplink[stackoverflow]{www.stackoverflow/1234}}
```

If you're using the `casual` or `banking` style, don't put the `\\` there, but use `\footersymbol` or `\maketitlesymbol` instead.

As for how hard it is to create macros for online profiles, it's planned for future versions of `moderncv` :)

Comment: works great, thanks.. and +1 for the link text, it was annoying the hell out of me.